# Cucumber setup - 'Search Marketplace for compatible editors (*.feature)' has encountered a problem

Tags: eclipse, installation, cucumber

I am trying to setup cucumber for the first time, following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHzMJuc9Zuk&list=PLFGoYjJG_fqoBFPevCDZDCufDX5h-o3yO&index=1) tutorial. I have configured the dependencies in my maven project, installed Natural plug-in, and am now attempting to create my feature file. When I try to create a file with .feature extension, I am encountering this error:

'Search Marketplace for compatible editors (*.feature)' has encountered a problem.
An internal error occurred during: "Search Marketplace for compatible editors (.feature)".

No idea what this means, can anyone help please?

Ross

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I had same issue.

1. Go to Eclipse Marketplace
2. Search for 'Natural' plugins and install.
3. Restart your Eclipse IDE.
4. Feature file icon changes and you can write your code and check in '.feature' file